# Is connected k-regular graphs are always vertex-transitive?

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

> A $k$-regular graph is a graph with all vertices having degree k.
>   A graph $X$ is called vertex-transitive if it's automorphism group acts transitively on the vertex set.
>
> We know that all the vertex-transitive graphs are regular graphs but my question is that whether the reverse of this statement true with the additional condition that graph is connected.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For example, the [Frucht graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht_graph) is 3 regular but not vertex transitive.

Comment: Then I have a counter question, what property of a connected k-regular graph makes it Vertex-Transitive.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NOT**.

> One may glue (in a sense) together two k-regular graphs of different nature so that the result will still be a $k$-regular graph but not vertex transitive. For instance:

Consider the complete graph $\ K_4\ $ and the graph $\ C\ $ of the edges of a $3$-cube; let $\ a\ $ be a vertex of $\ K_4,\ $ and $\ b\ $ and $\ c\ $ two opposite vertices of $\ C.\ $ Now, remove $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $, and glue the three hanging  edges of $\ K,\ $ and the three hanging edges of $\ C$--let them form three standard edges of the union $\ M\ $ which still is a regular $3$-regular graph. Then the remaining vertices of what was left from $\ K_3\ $ belong to a triangle of $\ M\ $ (it's enough to concentrate just on one of these vertices). On the other hand, the vertex $\ c\ $ does not belong to any triangle of $M$. ***END of CONSTRUCTION***

> Another description of the same example:

Observe that it has $\ 8\ $ vertices. Consider the
same $\ (C\ b\ c)\ $ as above. Let's remove $\ b\ $ and then add an end point to each hanging edge. Then let's add a triangle connecting the three new vertices. Thus we have now vertices which belong to a triangle while $\ c\ $ does not belong to any triangle.  ***END of CONSTRUCTION***

Enjoy.

> Would $\ 8\ $ be the smallest possible number of vertices of a contra-example for the ***Question***?

Actually, there is a 7-vertex example of a $2$-regular graph but it's not connected, namely:

> The disjoint union of a 3-cycle and a 4-cycle.